# Resources on the authentication cycle of SP2010

Tags: authentication, iis, lifecycle

I'm trying to find in-depth resources on the authentication cycle.

Things like:

- which HTTP requests are done in the process of authentication (mostly with claims based auth)
- which events can we bind to (in IIS, is SP). One particular event is the event that triggers the browser to show the default login window in Windows Claims Auth

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below links should comfortably get you all insights you need for claims authentication cycle.

**5 part Claims architecture series**

http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/claims-based-authentication/sharepoint-claims-based-authentication-architectures-explained-part-2-claims-architecture-priming/

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/itpro/Pages/An-Architecture-for-Claims-Based-Authorization-in-SharePoint.aspx

**Claims Auth Sequence**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147177.aspx#SPO_RA_ClaimsSequence

**Claims indepth**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx

**Extranet Topoloogies and Security Modeling**
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=eb4bff25-baba-4112-b518-f2fc442d5467

**Implementing Claims**
http://www.shailen.sukul.org/2010/03/claims-based-authentication-with.html

**Implementing SSO**
http://www.theidentityguy.com/articles/tag/sharepoint